# how to load custom staticresource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have to 2 files:
ButtonStyle.xaml and
ConstantsStyle.xaml

in App.xaml, i will init

```
    <Application.Resources>        
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Zalo;component/ResourceDictionary/480x800/ConstantsStyle.xaml"/>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Zalo;component/ResourceDictionary/480x800/ButtonStyle.xaml"/>
                 </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
......
    </Application.Resources>
```

file ConstantsStyle.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows">

    <Thickness x:Key="GenericButtonStylePadding">0,7</Thickness>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

file ButtonStyle.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
    xmlns:usercontrols="clr-namespace:Zalo.UserControls">

    <Style x:Key="GenericButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource GenericButtonStylePadding}"/>
   </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

App crash runtime. Because Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key GenericButtonStylePadding???

How can i run app correctly??? Please help me

Comment: Is the Build Action of the file Constants.xaml set to Resource?

Comment: @Perter: Yes, i can build my app, but i can't run

Comment: Yes the BuildAction is set to Resource?? Because you would also be able to build your app, when it's not set to Resource. Select the file Constants.xaml in Solution Explorer and press F4 for the Properties Window and set the BuildAction to Resource - should help.

Comment: @Peter: i set buildAction is Resource. not working :(

Comment: On top you mention Constants.xaml in code you refer ConstantsStyle.xaml? Just a typo?

Comment: Ops, Constants.xaml is ConstantsStyle.xaml, i will edit

Answer (score 1):

Try using DyanamicResource instead of StaticResource

```
<Style x:Key="GenericButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{DynamicResource GenericButtonStylePadding}"/>
   </Style>
```

Edit:
You can test one thing. Add another constant to Constant.XAML

```
<Brush x:Key="BGBrush">Black</Brush>
```

Try to use it in your ButtonStyle.XAML

```
<Style x:Key="GenericButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BGBrush}"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

See if button background changes to Black.
If color is changing then try something else than Thickness.

Comment: Sorry, i can't use DynamicResource

Comment: Try setting build action to Page. It is working for me.

Comment: Default build action is Page, and it's not working :(